# Issue with atlassian/scp-deploy exclude folder from SCP on bitbucket deploy pipeline

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

please help to understand, why I not able to exclude the folder from SCP on bitbucket deploy pipeline

There is my example :

```
image: php:7.2-fpm

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev mariadb-client
          - yes | pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
          - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - php artisan migrate
          - php artisan serve &
          - sleep 5
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
          - curl -vk http://localhost:8000
        services:
          - mysql
    - step:
        name: Deploy artifacts using SCP to DEV
        deployment: development
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:1.0.1
            variables:
              USER: $USER
              SERVER: $SERVER
              REMOTE_PATH: '/tmp/deploy'
              #REMOTE_PATH: '/srv/www/site.com/'
              LOCAL_PATH: '${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/*'
              EXTRA_ARGS: '--exclude=${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/vendor/* --exclude=${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/.env'

definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'test'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test'
```

This example is working, but due to "vendor" folder is huge, I want to exclude from SCP it.
Why on extra args exclude is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your "SCP" image on RSYNC one

```
pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.5.0
```

> https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/rsync-deploy/src/master/